# What is the logical difference between the below two python for loops?

Tags: python

I have a numpy array named circles whose 3rd column consists of radii values

```
circles=[
1358    254 113
1630    282 89
994     132 108
1204    742 103
976     638 100
1696    500 119
1256    468 106
1434    642 119]

def get_radius(circles):
    radii=[]
    for coordinates in circles[0,:]:
        radii.append(coordinates[2])
    return radii
```

The above function gives me the output

radii=
[113, 89, 108, 103, 100, 119, 106, 119]

As per my understanding the below code should also provide the  above radii values [113, 89, 108, 103, 100, 119, 106, 119]

```
def get_radius(circles):
    radii=[]
    for coordinates in circles:
        radii.append(coordinates[2])
    return radii
```

but it provides
radii=[
994
132
108
]

Comment: what's the output of `circles.shape`?

Comment: please fix the circles list it doesn't have any commas

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, you're essentially creating a new list containing only the last column and iterating through it, ence why the result

In the second loop, you're using your variable circle as a whole, so when you iterate through it it just seems to consider it as one object, and you're only appening it's 2nd column

At least that's my understanding

Comment: No, `[0,:]` is not taking the last column. If it were, then `coordinates[2]` would pick only `108` (the third value of the last column).

Comment: `[0,:]` is picking the whole set of rows and columns over which iterate, but we don't see that there's one outer dimension because the OP is not showing the valid code to generate the array.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the explanation provided by [IgnatiusReilly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73720455/16836078), you can perform a vectorized array to get the same desired answer.

```
circles[0,:,2]
array([113,  89, 108, 103, 100, 119, 106, 119])
```

Answer (score 0):

The array you have is

```
circles = np.array(
    [
        [
        [1358, 254, 113],
        [1630, 282, 89],
        [994, 132, 108],
        [1204, 742, 103],
        [976, 638, 100],
        [1696, 500, 119],
        [1256, 468, 106],
        [1434, 642, 119]
        ]
    ]
)


print(circles.shape)

# Prints
# (1, 8, 3)
```

This array has three dimensions, let's call them *x*, *y*, *z*.

If we do `circles[0,:]`, this takes the first element of *x* (which has only one element and every other element from the other dimensions:

```
print(circles[0,:])

# Prints
# [[1358  254  113]
#  [1630  282   89]
#  [ 994  132  108]
#  [1204  742  103]
#  [ 976  638  100]
#  [1696  500  119]
#  [1256  468  106]
#  [1434  642  119]]
```

So now, the loop is iteration over each `coordinate` in this array, i.e. each subarray *y*, and it takes the third element (the one with index 2).

In your second version of the loop, you start iterating through the elements of *x*, but *x* has only one single element, the array (*y*,*z*) and you take the third element, i.e. the third row `[ 994, 132, 108 ]`.

If you where to simplify your original array to eliminate the outer dimension, which seems unnecessary:

```
circles = circles[0,:]

print(circles.shape)
print(circles)

# Prints
# (8, 3)
# [[1358  254  113]
#  [1630  282   89]
#  [ 994  132  108]
#  [1204  742  103]
#  [ 976  638  100]
#  [1696  500  119]
#  [1256  468  106]
#  [1434  642  119]]
```

You could use now the second function without problem

```
def get_radius(circles):
    radii=[]
    for coordinates in circles:
        radii.append(coordinates[2])
    return radii

print(get_radius(circles))

# Prints
# [113, 89, 108, 103, 100, 119, 106, 119]
```

since now the loop iterates over each first level element in the simplify version of `circles` (each row *y*) and takes the third element.

Numpy arrays may be confusing and is a good practice for debugging to start by checking the `shape`.